# Implement NSLOOKUP into a program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, nslookup

I need to check if a domain exist in an RPGLE (or CLLE) program.

I can use in command line, example:

```
nslookup hostname(google.it)
```

There's a way to use the same command into a RPGLE (or CLLE) program? How can I check the result) Or alternatively is there an API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the output to a file like this

```
crtpf qtemp/stdout rcdlen(240)
ovrdbf stdout qtemp/stdout
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_QSH_CMD_OUTPUT) VALUE(STDOUT) LEVEL(*JOB)
NSLOOKUP HOSTNAME(google.it)
rmvENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_QSH_CMD_OUTPUT) LEVEL(*JOB)
```

but maybe [DIG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/dig.htm) output is easier to read by program (and [NSLOOKUP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/nslookup.htm) is deprecated)

```
crtpf qtemp/stdout rcdlen(240) 
ovrdbf stdout qtemp/stdout
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_QSH_CMD_OUTPUT) VALUE(STDOUT) LEVEL(*JOB)    
DIG HOSTNAME(google.it)
rmvENVVAR ENVVAR(QIBM_QSH_CMD_OUTPUT) LEVEL(*JOB)
```

Your you can just resolve with gethostbyname like [there](https://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/dns.html)